# Очень большой размер исполняемого модуля

Tags: linux, rust

Я - полный новичёк. Естественно, собрал и запустил hello_world. Потом посмотрел размер исполняемого модуля:

```
$ ls -l
итого 664
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary   4096 мар  1  2017 build
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary   4096 мар  1  2017 deps
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary   4096 мар  1  2017 examples
-rwxrwxr-x 1 lary lary 657056 мар  1  2017 hello_world
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary   4096 мар  1  2017 native
```

Цифра 657056 меня как-то огорчила. Я решил, что раз это дебажная сборка, то просто понапихали туда всякой отладочной информации, вот он и здоровенный такой. Решил собрать релиз. Посмотрел:

```
$ ls -l
итого 5152
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary    4096 май 22 17:57 build
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary    4096 май 22 17:57 deps
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary    4096 май 22 17:57 examples
-rwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary 5236496 май 22 17:57 hello_world
-rw-rw-r-- 1 lary lary     102 май 22 17:57 hello_world.d
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary    4096 май 22 17:57 incremental
drwxrwxr-x 2 lary lary    4096 май 22 17:57 native
```

И стало мне совсем грустно. Я что-то делаю не так? Или это - нормально? По всей видимости, собран модуль, в который статически прилинкован весь run-time. Так и должно быть ?

Comment: [Большие бинари в моем Rust? (Why is a Rust executable large?)](https://rustycrate.ru/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/2016/07/07/why-big-bin.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[En SO: Why are Rust executables so huge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008127/why-are-rust-executables-so-huge)

Если кратко, то rust по умолчанию влинковывает статически всю свою `libstd`. Дабы воздержать его от этого можно скормить ему `-C prefer-dynamic` в аргументы:

```
$ cat hw.rs
pub fn main() {
    println!("Hello world!");
}
$ rustc hw.rs -o hw-rust.static
$ rustc hw.rs -C prefer-dynamic -o hw-rust.dynamic
$ ls -lh hw*
-rw-r--r-- 1 alexander users   48 май 24 08:06 hw.rs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexander users  14K май 24 08:17 hw-rust.dynamic
-rwxr-xr-x 1 alexander users 3,0M май 24 08:16 hw-rust.static
```

**Update***

Стоит иметь в виду, что стабильного ABI у Rust [пока нет](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/600), и как soname, так и символы динамической линковки меняются от версии к версии. Единственный практически поддерживаемый вид динамических крейтов — [cdylib](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/linkage.html), но это используется для создания плагинов с C-совместимым внешним интерфейсом, а не для «родных» динамических библиотек.

<sub>* За замечание спасибо *@mzabaluev*</sub>

Comment: Это, действительно, решило проблему. Однако - вылезла другая:

*./hello_world
./hello_world: error while loading shared libraries: libstd-0006dc6e9901bcad.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

Comment: можно добавить в `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` путь к каталогу, где она лежит...

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, библиотеки rust лежат не по LIBRARY_PATH, а в моей домашней папке *:~/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib*. Её надо запихать в путь поиска библиотек ?

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!

Comment: Я не стал менять LD_LIBRARY_PATH, а сделал так:

*sudo ldconfig /home/lary/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/li*  Всё запускается.

Comment: на всякий случай, это тоже не столь перманентно, как может показаться — оно записывает только в `ld.so.cache`, который перезапишется при следующем вызове `ld-config`, например из пакетного менеджера при установке/удалении. Более постоянным способ будет прописать куда-нить в  `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/95my_rust.conf`... И не забывай, что это большая потенциальная дыра в безопасности т.к. эти библиотеки могут быть подгружены всеми пользователями, а доступны на запись даже непривилегированному... в этом плане лучше будет установить rust куда-нить за пределы своего домашнего каталога и запретить запись.

Comment: Короче, когда есть много вариантов - все они плохие! :-)

Comment: Стоит иметь в виду, что стабильного ABI у Rust пока нет, и как soname, так и символы динамической линковки меняются от версии к версии. Единственный практически поддерживаемый вид динамических крейтов — cdylib, но это используется для создания плагинов с C-совместимым внешним интерфейсом, а не для "родных" динамических библиотек Rust.

Comment: @mzabaluev есть какие-нить достоверные пруфлинки? хотел бы добавить замечание к ответу...

Comment: @Fat-Zer https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/600

Comment: @mzabaluev, нуда я тоже ничего интеречней не нашёл =))... добавил... спасибо...