# Как написать код на Rust чтобы он скомпилировался менее чем в 10 килобайт

Tags: rust

В C можно компоновать без стандартной библиотеки, но тогда возникнет проблема с точкой входа _start, но бинарник получится размером в 9 килобайт. Как написать код на Rust, чтоб бинарник был примерно такой

```
.global main
.text
main:
    ret
```

ну или хотя бы не 2 мегабайта.

Comment: См. https://github.com/johnthagen/min-sized-rust.

Comment: А если не ссылаться на что-то ?

Comment: Я уже гуглил, не переживайте

Comment: @Ainar-G можете привести код пожалуйста ?

Comment: @Антон, господи, по ссылке написана даже последовательность шагов, неужели лень посмотреть? Размер бинарника зависит не только от кода.

Comment: собственно почти весь объём какого-нить hello world'а занимает libstd... собственно, можно использовать один из способов по ссылке выше (`lto`, `#![no_std]`), а можно прилинковать её [динамически](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832630/%d0%9e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d1%8f%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f/832653#832653)